# Maven minify plugin not found

Tags: maven-plugin, minify

In the past couple of hours I was looking for maven-minify 1.4-order plugin.
Can somebody give me it because I couldn't find it in internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maven Minify Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-samaxes-plugin/) was renamed to [Minify Maven Plugin](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin) and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin).